# how to get Device UUID using C#

Tags: c#, .net, uuid

I want to get Device UUID using C#. The ID I needs can get using `wmic csproduct get uuid` cmd command. I try to run this command in C# cmd process, but it not gives the only UUID as output. It gives all of the cmd text as output. So, how could i get Device UUID in C#. I use .net framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a regular expression to filter the output from wmic:

```cs
private string GetUuid()
{
    try
    {
        var proc = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "wmic.exe",
            Arguments = "csproduct get uuid",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        });
        if (proc != null)
        {
            string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            // Search for UUID string
            var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(output, @"[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}");
            if (match.Success) { return match.Value; }
        }
    }
    catch { }  // Your exception handling
    return null;  // Or string.Empty
}
```